# Activiti: When a CallActivity fails, the Workflow never ends

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I'm facing a problem with asynchronous workflows.
I have this design:

**workflow1:**

`start -> ScriptActivity1` *(is throwing a NullPointerException to test error handling)*`-> end`

**workflow2:**

`start -> CallActivity` *(which calls **workflow1**)* `-> end`

---

I'm seeing that if I deploy the workflow as asynchronous, if **workflow1** fails, the **workflow2** never ends, but this isn't happening when the they are deployed as synchronous.

Also, if I execute workflow1 only, it fails correctly showing the corresponding exception.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Are you handling the NPE somewhere ? If not,  this is the expected behaviour when you have async tasks. When Activiti gets a technical exception (anyone that is not a subclass of BpmnError) from an activity, it will retry it a number of times. After the retry limit is reached, the engine gives up, but the corresponding job is kept in the control table - at least for the "classical" job executor. The assumption is that technical errors in production are usually caused by transient problems like an external servive being unavailable. You can restart a failed job using the API or a db update.

Answer (score 0):

It all has to do with how the threading model works.
I imagine your "test" processes don't have an human tasks which is why you are experiencing the behavior that you are.
Synchronous processes run on the same thread as the initiator until such time as they hit a wait state (message listener, human task or signal listener typically). So, when your workflow 1 process fails, it will kill workflow2.

When things are asynchronous, the job schedule is what kicks off your called process and it is essentially a stand alone process (although does have a reference to its parent). When workflow 1 fails, workflow 2 continues along happily.

Typically you model yourself out of the behavior you are experiencing by using signal catch boundary listeners that are triggered by a signal throw event on the exception path.

Let me know if you want a diagrammatic example.

Comment: Thanks a lot!.. I've reading in Activiti docs about boundary listeners but it isn't clear for me.. I'd really appreciate that you give a nice graph where I can see the concept. Thanks again.